# Nested group in a Vuetify v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to achieve the following layout with nested group of items inside a column of a row of a v-data-table as a vuetify component and wonder if there is a way to solve this with a nested group of v-data-table:

[image: Current solution with v-list-group]

currently the code looks something like this:

```
<v-data-table v-model:items-per-page="itemsPerPage" :items="filteredChannels" :group-by="groupBy" :search="search"
      item-value="name" class="elevation-1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Channel Name</th>
          <th>Source Connector Name</th>
          <th>Source Connector Transport Name</th>
          <th>Source Connector Enabled</th>
          <th>Source Connector Inbound Data Type</th>
          <th>Source Connector Host</th>
          <th>Source Connector Port</th>
          <th>Source Connector SMB Host</th>
          <!-- TODO: add option for groupBy each destinations array as own group -->
          <th>Destinations Collection</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(item) in filteredChannels" :key="item.name">
          <!-- general -->
          <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
          <!-- source connector -->
          <td>{{ item.sourceConnector.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.sourceConnector.transportName }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.sourceConnector.enabled }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.sourceConnector.inboundDataType }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.sourceConnector.host }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.sourceConnector.port }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.sourceConnector.smbHost }}</td>
          <!-- destination connectors -->
          <td style="width: 400px">
            <v-list>
              <v-list-group value="Destinations">
                <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
                  <v-list-item v-bind="props" title="Destinations"></v-list-item>
                </template>
                <v-list-item v-for="(destination, i) in item.destinationConnectors" :key="i" :title="destination.title">
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list-group>
            </v-list>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</v-data-table>
```

and the data structure looks like this. I also need some additional columns inside the groups:

```
{
  "channels": [
      {
          "name": "Multi Destinations Channel",
          "id": "ef7bb8c3-af5f-4a9c-bccc-5a94c1aaaa9a",
          "sourceConnector": {
              "name": "sourceConnector",
              "transportName": "HTTP Listener",
              "enabled": "true",
              "inboundDataType": "XML",
              "host": "0.0.0.0",
              "port": "80",
              "smbHost": ""
          },
          "destinationConnectors": [
              {
                  "name": "Destination 1",
                  "title": "Destination 1",
                  "parentId": "ef7bb8c3-af5f-4a9c-bccc-5a94c1aaaa9a",
                  "outboundDataType": "HL7V2"
              },
              {
                  "name": "Destination 2",
                  "title": "Destination 2",
                  "parentId": "ef7bb8c3-af5f-4a9c-bccc-5a94c1aaaa9a",
                  "outboundDataType": "HL7V2"
              },
              /* {...} */
          ]
      }
  ]
}
```